# Async method statements are not getting executed

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I ahve implemented Async method using `@Async` Spring 3.0

my problem is i am not able to see the logs from that method(nor the functionality is getting executed), if i remove `@Async` annotation i am able to see logs and functionality also gets executed!

has anyone faced such issue ever? please guide

Class : `ContactsCreationUtil`

```
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;

import <package_name>.entity.ContactDetails;
import <package_name>.contactsdir.rest.IContactsDirRestService;

public class ContactCreationUtil {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactCreationUtil.class);

    private IContactsDirRestService contactDirectoryRestService;

    public IContactsDirRestService getContactDirectoryRestService() {
        return contactDirectoryRestService;
    }

    public void setContactDirectoryRestService(
            IContactsDirRestService contactDirectoryRestService) {
        this.contactDirectoryRestService = contactDirectoryRestService;
    }

    @Async
    public void initiateContactCreation(String fromUserId, List<String> toUsers){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        logger.info("init cont creation");
        try {
            ContactDetails contactDetails = new ContactDetails();
            contactDetails.setFromUserId(fromUserId);
            contactDetails.setContactEmailIds(toUsers.toArray(new String[toUsers.size()]));
            contactDirectoryRestService.addContact(contactDetails);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("init cont creation done");
    }

}
```

Configuration in `module-context.xml`

```
<bean id="contactCreationUtil" class="<package_name>.ContactCreationUtil">
        <property name="contactDirectoryRestService" ref="contactDirectoryRestService" />
    </bean>
```

`contactDirectoryRestService` is injected through OSGI context and it is a function in other OSGI bundle.

and I have referred above `contactCreationUtil` in my bean from where i am calling the async function like following

```
<property name="contactCreationUtil" ref="contactCreationUtil"/>
```

and i have created following variable in my class to use this referance

```
private ContactCreationUtil contactCreationUtil;

    public ContactCreationUtil getContactCreationUtil() {
        return contactCreationUtil;
    }

    public void setContactCreationUtil(ContactCreationUtil contactCreationUtil) {
        this.contactCreationUtil = contactCreationUtil;
    }
```

and i am calling that function like following

```
contactCreationUtil.initiateContactCreation(userId, toUsersList);
```

Comment: Could you post your code along with your Spring configuration?

Comment: @geoand updated my question, please guide if you have any idea

Comment: Are you using a task executor from Spring? See the documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: no i am not using that, is it mandatory to use?

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is. Whenever I used @Async I always had a task executor

Comment: is it? i mean in many examples i just saw use of only `Async` like one here http://java-success.blogspot.com/2013/05/asynchronous-processiong-with-spring.html

Comment: As you can see in section 25.5.3 of http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html "to enable both `@Scheduled` and `@Async` annotations, simply include the 'annotation-driven' element from the task namespace in your configuration."

Comment: i have the same in my `module-context.xml`

Comment: Can you share your code on GitHub or something?